# Can't print each song title from a chart. Getting AttributeError?

Tags: python, list, indexing, error-handling

Here's the short code:

```
Import billboard
chart = billboard.ChartData('hot-100')
song = chart[0:99]
print(song.title)
```

Here's the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Billboardtop100weekly", line 7, in <module>
 print(song.title)
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'
```

Tried to replicate this [api](https://github.com/guoguo12/billboard-charts), to extract the song titles from the list, but i don't know how. Any help appreciated

Comment: It is telling you that `song` is a list and does not have an attribute named `title`. To see what is in the `song` variable try `print(str(song))`.

Comment: If `chart` is a list of songs, then `chart[0:99]` is a list of the first 99 songs from `chart`. That's different from the `chart[0]` in the Quickstart docs, which is just the first song, not a list. If you want to print the titles of 99 songs, you need a loop, like `songs = chart[0:99]`, then `for song in songs: print(song.title)`.

Comment: But meanwhile, why are you doing `char[0:99]` in the first place? Did you actually want the top 99 songs out of 100? Or were you trying to write something different, and just used the wrong syntax? If you can explain what you wanted, we can probably explain how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chart` is a list of song objects.

So, this code in the Quickstart docs:

```
>>> song = chart[0]  # Get no. 1 song on chart
>>> song.title
```

… is getting the first song object, and then getting its title. That's what `[0]` means: you're asking for the element at index #0.

But this code from your question:

```
song = chart[0:99]
print(song.title)
```

… is getting a slice of the first 99 song objects—which is still a list of songs, not a song—and then trying to get its title. That's what `[0:99]` means: you're asking for all of the elements from index #0 to (but not including) index #99, which is going to be a list. And lists don't have titles.

If you want to print the titles of the top 99 out of 100 songs, you need to loop over that slice. Like this:

```
songs = chart[0:99]
for song in songs:
    print(song.title)
```